How to formulate piecewise quadratic function optimization without introducing binary variables?
I have a problem with logical constraints (either-or constraints). I know that it can be solved by either big-M or complementary formulations. However, i do not want to convert it into mixed-integer problem. I found a paper that converts this either-or constraint into a continuous penalty function so that it can be solved using continuous optimization solvers.
https://enac.hal.science/hal-03623407/document
They proposed piecewise quadratic function to model this penalty function.
Penalty function
The function appears to be concave (correct me if i am wrong). 3d graph of penalty function
I know how to formulate an optimization problem when maximizing piecewise linear concave function without introducing sos2 constraints. I don't understand how to formulate minimize piecewise quadratic concave function without introducing sos2 constraints or binary variable. can anyone help me understand how this is formulated without sos2 constraints or binary variable? Thank you in advance!

Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471713/how-to-formulate-piecewise-quadratic-function-optimization-without-introducing-b
